# control an Automated function manually

Tags: java, android, backendless

Well I  apologize for not so specific and clear title (tried too hard for it ), so I have this function

```
public void fetchData(){
    dataQuery.setPageSize(10); // fetch 10 items per request 
    final boolean[] firstResponse = {true};
    final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch( 1 );

    // a callback of fetching data from server 
    Backendless.Data.of(Note.class).find(dataQuery, new AsyncCallback<BackendlessCollection<Note>>() {
        @Override
        public void handleResponse(BackendlessCollection<Note> notes) { // here we have the response of request 

             /// loop for  requesting for items until all of them is fetched////// 
            if(firstResponse[0])
            {
                firstResponse[0] =false;
            }
            int size = notes.getCurrentPage().size();
            if( size > 0 )

                notes.nextPage( this );

            else
                latch.countDown();

           //////////////////////////////////

         /// do whatever I want with the fetched data


 }

        @Override
        public void handleFault(BackendlessFault fault) {// here we have the error  of request 

            swipeToReload.setRefreshing(false);
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "" + fault.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
    }
```

so now the above function is fetching `10 items` per request in a loop and this loop runs until all the data is retrieved, what I want is to make this loop run manually (on a button click I want to load the first 10 items, then instead of requesting again I want it to work manually, fetch the next 10 items on button click) if anybody can guide me to right direction then it'll be so helpful for me

Answer (score 1):

Remove countdown latch and change the signature like this:

```
public void fetchData( int offset )
```

In the implementation, keep the code to set the page size, but also add this:

```
dataQuery.setOffset( offset );
```

That will fetch the next page of data from the specified offset. There is no need to call nextPage in the responder. The result you get will be the block of "pageSize" records from the specified offset.

Comment: thanks a lot  for responding , can you please explain this `dataQuery.setOffset( offset )` ?

Comment: all objects loaded from the server are organized sequentially. First object has offset 0, second has offset 1 and so on. When you set offset using dataQuery.setOffset, you instruct the server to load the next "page" of objects from the specified offset.